# android get notified when an image is deleted from sdcard

Tags: android, database, image, provider

I have an application which manages a local table with the images from the Media.Images content provider along with some additional parameters. So for the new images I just query the content provider with a timestamp and get all the newer images since the last sync.  But what I am having issue with is the deleted images.  How do i get info on which images have been deleted or maybe get somehow notified by a broadcast or something like that when an image has been deleted?  Currently to get the info on which images are deleted I run a service which flags the ones that exist in my table and afterwards removes the ones that don't, but that is kind of a slow process and I am looking to improve it.